# Make Tabs Selected Programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I have seven tabs named 'Sunday' to 'Saturday' in my app. Now I want My App to automatically select tab based on current day i.e. If today is Friday, the Friday tab should be automatically selected when my app runs. How can I achieve this. Please help.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.kiran.herau;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    FloatingActionButton fab_plus, fab_facebook, fab_gmail;
    Animation FabOpen, FabClose, FabRClockwise, FabRAnticlockwise;
    boolean isOpen = false;

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_addschedule) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SentFragment()).commit();

                }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_smsschedule) {

//                    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smsschedule);
//                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
//
//
//                        @Override
//                        public void onClick(View v) {
//                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
//                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,LayoutPrimary.class));
//
//                        }
//                    });

                }
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_settings) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
                }
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_aboutus) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,pop.class));                }
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_share) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        fab_plus = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_plus);
        fab_facebook=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_facebook);
        fab_gmail=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_gmail);
        FabOpen= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_open);
        FabClose= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        FabRClockwise= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotateclockwise);
        FabRAnticlockwise= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondactivity);
        fab_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isOpen) {
                    fab_facebook.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_gmail.startAnimation(FabClose);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRAnticlockwise);
                    fab_facebook.setClickable(false);
                    fab_gmail.setClickable(false);
                    isOpen = false;
                }
                else {
                    fab_facebook.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_gmail.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                    fab_plus.startAnimation(FabRClockwise);
                    fab_facebook.setClickable(true);
                    fab_gmail.setClickable(true);
                    isOpen = true;
                }
            }
        });
        fab_facebook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this,PopView.class));

            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this,ForthActivity.class));

            }
        });

        fab_gmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this,PopAdd.class));

            }
        });




//
//
//        fab_gmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//
//
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this,PopAdd.class));
//
//            }
//        });

//        OnClickButtonListener();



    }

//
//    public void OnClickButtonListener() {
//        fab_gmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//s
//
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.kiran.herau.SecondActivity");
//                startActivity(intent);
//
//
//            }
//        });


}
```

TabFragment.java

```
package com.example.kiran.herau;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
        import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;

        import layout.PrimaryFragment;
        import layout.SocialFragment;
        import layout.UpdatesFragment;

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 7 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */


        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
                case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
                case 2 : return new UpdatesFragment();
                case 3 : return new PrimaryFragment();
                case 4 : return new PrimaryFragment();
                case 5 : return new UpdatesFragment();
                case 6 : return new UpdatesFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "S";
                case 1 :
                    return "M";
                case 2 :
                    return "T";
                case 3 :
                    return "W";
                case 4 :
                    return "T";
                case 5 :
                    return "F";
                case 6 :
                    return "S";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0):

```
package events.chitva.com.events.CalendarLib;


import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * @author Amir
 * @author ebraminio
 */
public class GregorianDate extends AbstractDate {
    private static final int[] daysInMonth = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31,
            31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    public GregorianDate() {
        this(Calendar.getInstance());
    }

    public GregorianDate(Calendar calendar) {
        this.year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        this.day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    }

    public GregorianDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        this();
        setYear(year);
        setMonth(month);
        setDayOfMonth(day);
    }

    public int getDayOfMonth() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDayOfMonth(int day) {
        if (day < 1)
            throw new DayOutOfRangeException("day " + day + " is out of range!");

        if (month != 2 && day > daysInMonth[month])
            throw new DayOutOfRangeException("day " + day + " is out of range!");

        if (month == 2 && isLeapYear() && day > 29)
            throw new DayOutOfRangeException("day " + day + " is out of range!");

        if (month == 2 && (!isLeapYear()) && day > 28)
            throw new DayOutOfRangeException("day " + day + " is out of range!");

        // TODO check for the case of leap year for February
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getDayOfWeek() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }

    public int getDayOfYear() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setMonth(int month) {
        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
            throw new MonthOutOfRangeException("month " + month
                    + " is out of range!");

        // Set the day again, so that exceptions are thrown if the
        // day is out of range
        setDayOfMonth(getDayOfMonth());

        this.month = month;
    }

    public int getWeekOfMonth() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public int getWeekOfYear() {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        if (year == 0)
            throw new YearOutOfRangeException("Year 0 is invalid!");

        this.year = year;
    }

    public boolean isLeapYear() {
        if (year % 400 == 0)
            return true;
        else if (year % 100 == 0)
            return false;
        return (year % 4 == 0);
    }

    public void rollDay(int amount, boolean up) {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public void rollMonth(int amount, boolean up) {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public void rollYear(int amount, boolean up) {
        throw new RuntimeException("not implemented yet!");
    }

    public boolean equals(GregorianDate gregorianDate) {
        return this.getDayOfMonth() == gregorianDate.getDayOfMonth()
                && this.getMonth() == gregorianDate.getMonth()
                && this.getYear() == gregorianDate.getYear();
    }

    @Override
    public GregorianDate clone() {
        return new GregorianDate(getYear(), getMonth(), getDayOfMonth());
    }
}
```

use this library. then call

```
Date d = new Date();
new GregorianDate(1900 + d.getYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate()).getDayOfWeek();
```

Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Tablayout.Tab` at the position corresponding to the current day with [getTabAt(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#getTabAt(int)), and select it with [select()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#select()).

If you do this in `onCreate` of the Activity, or `onCreateView` of the Fragment, then the right tab will be automatically selected on startup.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Find out which day is today
        int dayIndex = getCurrentDayIndex();

        // Select the corresponding tab
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(dayIndex);
        tab.select();

        return x;

    }
```